# Google script - get specific data from website

Tags: string, url, google-apps-script

It seems I have a very basic question:

I try to get the content of a website and search within for substrings of interest.
Let's take [this site](http://www.faz.net/suche/?query=google&suchbegriffImage.x=0&suchbegriffImage.y=0&resultsPerPage=20) for example.

I tried to find the total number of results for Google at this newspaper's archive.

For this purpose I went for

```
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getContentText();
var  Osheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('output');
var begin = page.indexOf('<span class="Trefferzahl">',1)+26 //starting substring
var finish = page.indexOf('<span class',begin) // finishing substring
var result0 = page.substring(begin, finish - begin);

var Osheet.getRange('A1').setValue(result0)
```

However as result I get some string that has nothing to do with what I searches for.
It should return:

> 6611 Treffer zu "google"

But it returns this:

> "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a
> single cell."

That of course makes no sense as there are some 25 letters all together.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you debug it, then? `Logger.log(result0)` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finish` number will be greater than the `begin` number.  `finish - begin` will be a negative number.  That's not what you want.  This line:

var result0 = page.substring(begin, finish - begin);

should be:

```
var result0 = page.substring(begin, finish);
```